# Subscription mysteriously not triggering

Tags: angular, observable, angularfire2, google-cloud-firestore

So I'm using Angular and Firestore. For some reason, I can subscribe to the observable fine in one spot but not the other and I can't figure out why. I feel like it may be because I'm subscribed somewhere with it once. Can I not have a 
 running subscription and use take(1) at the same time or something? I'm getting no errors, it simply stops there.

```
private jobDoc: AngularFirestoreDocument<Job>;
job: Observable<Job>;


ngOnInit() {
  this.route.params.subscribe(jobId => {
    this.createJobPage().then(function(result){
      this.job.subscribe(job => {
        console.log('this works');
      });
    }.bind(this));
  });
}


// When I load the page we run this function
createJobPage() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve){
    this.getUser().then(user => {
      this.jobDoc = this.afs.doc(`accounts/${user['cid']}/jobs/jobId`);
      this.job = this.jobDoc.valueChanges();
      this.job.take(1).subscribe(job => {
        console.log('this works');
      });
      resolve();
    });
  }.bind(this));
}


// Clicking a button saves the info
saveNewJob() {
  this.getUser().then(function(user) {
    console.log('this works, and shows "this.job" is an observable', this.job);
    this.jobDoc.update({id: 1})   // If I add this line it all works
    this.job.take(1).subscribe(job => {
      console.log('this does not work'); // This doesn't work
    });
    console.log('This works');
  }.bind(this));
}
```

-------- UPDATE --------

I think it's a bug. This works:

```
this.jobDoc.update({id: 1})
this.job.take(1).subscribe(job => {
  console.log('this works');
});
```

but if I remove the `jobDoc` update it doesn't work, like this:

```
this.job.take(1).subscribe(job => {
  console.log('this works');
});
```

So it seems if I want to subscribe to this, I need to first give `jobDoc` a bit of a kick to wake it up... anyone know why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This really had me curious so I went to firebase source docs and found this https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/src/firestore/observable/fromRef.ts

valueChanges is built from those functions, and the key part is this:

```
export function fromRef<R>(ref: firebase.firestore.DocumentReference | 
    firebase.firestore.Query) {
    return _fromRef<typeof ref, R>(ref).share();
}
```

This is a shared observable, so once it completes, it's done for all current and future subscribers.  So the initial take(1) completes it, and then any future subscribers will not get anything from it, this is why rereferencing it works, because it recreates the shared observable.

Answer (score 1):

maybe try using `first()` instead of `take(1)`, take 1 emits 1 and unsubscribes.

Comment: Edited the code, but still getting the same issue. `this.job` is showing as an observable when I console.log it, just before trying to subscribe, so I think it's in-scope. Subscribe just doesn't seem to trigger on it. I do feel it could be a scope issue, but not sure how, since when I console.log it, I get the observable and not `undefined`

Comment: Ok, I edited the above code a bit. Still doesn't work. See changes, it's definitely not a scope issue because I can use update on the reference no problem.

Answer (score 0):

To fix it I just re-set `this.job` but I have no idea why I needed to do that. Maybe a bug? If anyone knows, LMK

```
this.job = this.jobDoc.valueChanges();
this.job.take(1).subscribe(snap => {
  console.log('WORKED!');
});
```

Comment: looks to me like you have some kind of scope issue where "job" isn't getting defined in the same scope. What happens if you stop binding "this" and just use arrow functions instead

Comment: I just swapped out all functions for arrow functions and removed all bindings. Still have the same issue, but much cleaner without `bind(this)` everywhere lol. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Not a bug, `this.job` is a reference of `this.jobDoc`

after further review `saveNewJob()` was adding a subscriber without a trigger.

adding the `this.jobDoc.update` is the trigger :)

```
saveNewJob() {
  this.getUser().then(function(user) {
    console.log('this works, and shows "this.job" is an observable', this.job);
    this.jobDoc.update({id: 1})   // If I add this line it all works
    this.job.take(1).subscribe(job => {
      console.log('this does not work'); // This doesn't work
    });
    console.log('This works');
  }.bind(this));
}
```

Comment: Doesn't `this.job.take(1).subscribe()` trigger it immediately? And if not, I'm not sure why it works the first time when I first initialize it, but not later. `this.job` triggers immediately when I first subscribe in `createJobPage()`, when the page loads, but not later when I click save...

Comment: `this.jobDoc = this.afs.doc(\`accounts/${user['cid']}/jobs/jobId\`);` that is the line that triggers the first one, `valueChanges()` syncs all the data at that route, anytime items at the path are updated and there are subscribers an event will be triggered.